# Getting an error saying I cannot import name 'home'

Tags: python, flask

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/038fd28191f3a48904f5604b75d77d51.png]

```
from views import home
from views import contact
app.register_blueprint(home.mod)
app.register_blueprint(contact.mod)
```

This is the error I get

```
(venv) REMOVED@REMOVED:~/ntc/app$ python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 30, in <module>
    from views.home import home
  File "/home/REMOVED/ntc/app/views/home.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main import *
  File "/home/REMOVED/ntc/app/main.py", line 30, in <module>
    from views.home import home
  ImportError: cannot import name 'home'
```

It works when I use it on my Windows version of Python, and it works fine. I don't understand how this issue is happening to me with the same Python version and same everything basically.

Comment: Cyclic imports?

Comment: Try putting a blank file inside your `views` directory named `__init__.py`.

Comment: @coralv I tried this less than an hour ago and still no luck unfortunately. :( If it helps I'm using Python3 on both Windows & Ubuntu.

Comment: Try rename your home.py module to something else, eg. myhome.py

Comment: Another try,  add a .  in front.  from .views import myhome

Comment: @Skycc, I'm still getting the same thing. Something I noticed however was that my Ubuntu is using 3.4.1 and my Windows is using 3.5.2.. Could this be messing up the layout of everything for me this whole time?

Comment: Can,t think of anything due to versioning. Still version 3 though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution, it's hard to explain but I'm normally a PHP developer that just transitioned to Python so I'm not used to using `:` instead of `{ }` interestingly enough even though the error was saying something relating with the import. It actually wasn't that, it was a stupid bracket I had a few lines up of the file.

I apologize deeply!